# Saving Images in to local folder in android

Tags: android

I created android app which reads images from url. Now I want to store those images in local file structure or SD Card. so i created a folder names "images" in my android project and added image xyz.png manually to test reading of images.

and wrote below code to read.

```
  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/images/xyz.png");

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgViewId);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

But eclipse says unable to find the resource!!

What is the best way to store and read images in android app?

I did caching but cache get clears if i force close the app.

I want to store in android mobile/tablet and it should be part of app.

Comment: are you interested to store the images local to your application or into the sdcard?

Comment: yes local to application not to SD card

Comment: sharath kindly guide. alejandrocordon's code returning null.

Comment: why dont you store the image onto the sdcard and make the file invisible so that no other application can see it or use that file?

Comment: what if there is no SD card available? ok then what is the way to add resource to SD Card?

Comment: @iShare you should know that reading images from URL and from resources are different tasks. So focus on one task, update your question so, that people know exactly what you want to do - read from URL either read from resources.

Comment: Edited my post. Actually I want to read from URL and store it in folder. reading from URL works fine and i successfully added to cache. but cache get clears if i force close. So i want to add to some folder in local or SD card so that next time i read from local or SD Card instead of URL.

Comment: give a look at this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-image-in-sdcard.html . I think this will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

try the enviroment variable to get the directoty

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/images/xyz.png");
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/images/xyz.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try to this ....

```
private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
  ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
  File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  myInternalFile = new File(directory , "abc.png");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
  bMap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos); //output image is the image bitmap that you obtain
```

Check this [android description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)